# Prestashop 1.6 redirect loop on backoffice filters

Tags: redirect, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, redirect-loop

I have a problem with line filters in backoffice of Prestashop 1.6. Every time I use them (it doesn't matter if in products, orders etc.) i get a redirect loop.

I think there is some error in URL parameter `submitFilterproduct` (and analogic ones for orders etc.), because **only if it's set to non zero value** (and line filters set it to 1) loop occurs.

Also I found out that the page redirects to itself (using code 302)

Do you know where the problem could be?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on this page:

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/480490-category-search-and-listing-in-bo-after-upgrade-to-1612/

There is broken piece of code in AdminController. By commenting it the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In general this worry appears when you connect to your backoffice with a different url than the one in the Settings -> Seo & Url tab.

Ex: if declared in url www.mysite.com, then your backoffice url should be http://www.example.com/backoffice, not http://example.com/backoffice

Comment: I use non-www address only and seo seems to be OK. It wasn't a case but thank you for your help. The right answer follows.